# Optimal length close to Entropy plus 1

Tags: probability, coding-theory, information-theory

For a fixed $\epsilon> 0$, one need to find a probability distribution $\bf{p}=(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n)$ and an optimal code (prefix-free) for this distribution such that the average length $L=\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_il_i$ is arbitrarily close to $H(\bf{p})$$+1$, i.e, $L< H+1-\epsilon$.

I tried assigning $p_2=p_3=\ldots=p_N=p,\ p_1= 1-(N-1)p$ and computed the entropy.But I am getting stuck in finding the optimal code length which is given by Huffman Code. Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: Why did you assign that two-valued distribution?

Comment: @kodlu : So that it would be easier to calculate the Huffman code's length.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2614628/how-to-maximise-the-difference-between-entropy-and-expected-length-of-an-huffman/4525554#4525554.